# Advanced audio management with FMOD in LibGDX

Tags: java, audio, libgdx, fmod

There is any way to run FMOD in libgdx?
My sound designer uses FMOD studio and I need to implement audio banks in our games.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No.
"FMOD is an easy to use crossplatform audio engine, available on the Windows, Windows CE, Linux, Macintosh, GameCube, Playstation 2 and XBox platforms. It can be used with C/C++, Visual Basic,Delphi and MASM. So, if you use one of those languages on one of these platforms and you want to use sound in your application, FMOD is made for you. The examples below will be in C although thebasic principles should be the same across all platforms.

Alternatives

One alternative might be OpenAL. OpenAL is another crossplatform audio API which is available for Windows, Linux and Macintosh and can be used with C/C++,Delphi and Java. The style is similar to OpenGL (for example, the extensions technique is also used here).
A Windows-specific alternative would be DirectSound which is part of Microsoft's DirectX."
[reference](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-quick-guide-to-fmod-r2098)

Although you can Natively make some libs and stuff in java to make it work for you, but i don't it'll worth it.

Comment: Another alternative if you know Pure data : gdx-pd extension is here : https://github.com/mgsx-dev/gdx-pd